# angular 2 (click) passing iteration variable and [class.selected] passing function

Tags: angular

The following is taken from ng-book 2

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'products-list',
  directives: [ProductRow],
  inputs: ['productList'],
  outputs: ['onProductSelected'],
  template: `
  <div class="ui items">
    <product-row 
      *ngFor="let myProduct of productList" 
      [product]="myProduct" 
      (click)='clicked(myProduct)'
      [class.selected]="isSelected(myProduct)">
    </product-row>
  </div>
  `
})
class ProductsList {
  /**
   * @input productList - the Product[] passed to us
   */
  productList: Product[];

  /**
   * @ouput onProductSelected - outputs the current 
   *          Product whenever a new Product is selected
   */
  onProductSelected: EventEmitter<Product>;

  /**
   * @property currentProduct - local state containing 
   *             the currently selected `Product`
   */
  currentProduct: Product;

  constructor() {
    this.onProductSelected = new EventEmitter();
  }

  clicked(product: Product): void {
    this.currentProduct = product;
    this.onProductSelected.emit(product);
  }

  isSelected(product: Product): boolean {
    if (!product || !this.currentProduct) {
      return false;
    }
    return product.sku === this.currentProduct.sku;
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'product-row',
  inputs: ['product'],
  ... not relevant to the question
  `
})
class ProductRow {
  product: Product;
}
```

Two questions,

Q1. where it says

```
(click)='clicked(myProduct)'
```

is the argument for clicked the same as the product property on ProductRow component? I am used to passing $event to clicked. Why pass "myProduct" instead?

Q2. where it says

```
[class.selected]="isSelected(myProduct)"
```

it seems like we are doing

```
[class.selected]="false"
```

for all products cuz none of them is selected initially.
How is angular able to call isSelected(myProduct) again and again? How does angular decide when to call isSelected?

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of `parent-child` communication in angular2.

when you are using `(click)='clicked(myProduct)'` event, what essentially you are doing is `emitting` the value of the selected product using  `@ouput onProductSelected` property as shown here :

```
this.onProductSelected.emit(product);
$event` here would be equivalent to `#myProduct.value
```

when any event gets executed, angular2's change detections kicks-in; checking all the template expression values. It then updates the property binding as per value changes. now everytime value of `myProduct` changes, the property binding `[class.selected]` need to get updated , hence `isSelected` method gets called.